# PyroCMS 2.2.1 (CodeIgniter) login attempt not redirecting with mod_rewrite

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

I have a simple PyroCMS 2.2.1 site which uses the default home page and login system on Apache (2.2.25, I think!). In my local environment (OS X 10.7/Apache 2.2.22), everything works as expected. We had some issues getting mod_rewrite to work, but now the URLs are clean and it appears to be working -- except that we can't log in with the form.

The issue appears to be with the login request. The login does not work when the request is sent like:

```
http://www.ourdomain.com/users/login?email=admin&password=123456&btnLogin=Login
```

But! It does work when it includes index.php. Like so:

```
http://games.coe.uky.edu/index.php/users/login?email=admin&password=123456&btnLogin=Login
```

I was able to brute force it by adding index.php to the form action, but I'm certain that should not be necessary. I did look over several CodeIgniter and PyroCMS forum posts, but I did not find a solution.

More background: after enabling mod_rewrite in Apache, we adjusted the system/cms/config/config.php to show:

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

Here is a copy of our .htaccess file:

```
# Multiple Environment config
# Set this to development, staging or production
SetEnv PYRO_ENV development

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    # Make sure directory listing is disabled
    Options +FollowSymLinks -Indexes
    # disable the Apache MultiViews directive if it is enabled on the server. It plays havoc with URL rewriting
    Options -MultiViews
    RewriteEngine on

    # Automatically determine and set the PYRO_ENV variable
  #RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^local.domain.com$
  #RewriteRule (.*) $1 [E=PYRO_ENV:development]

  #RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^stage.domain.com$
  #RewriteRule (.*) $1 [E=PYRO_ENV:staging]

  #RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.com$
  #RewriteRule (.*) $1 [E=PYRO_ENV:production]

    # NOTICE: If you get a 404 play with combinations of the following commented out lines
    #AllowOverride All
    #RewriteBase /home/supers/htdocs

    # Restrict your site to only one domain
    # !important USE ONLY ONE OPTION

    # Option 1: To rewrite "www.domain.com -> domain.com" uncomment the following lines.
    #RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    #RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
    #RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

    # Option 2: To rewrite "domain.com -> www.domain.com" uncomment the following lines.
    #RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    #RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\..+$ [NC]
    #RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (.+)$ [NC]
    #RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%1/$1 [R=301,L]

    # Keep people out of codeigniter directory and Git/Mercurial data
    RedirectMatch 403 ^/.*/(system/cms/cache|system/codeigniter|system/cms/config|system/cms/logs|\.git|\.hg).*$

    # Send request via index.php (again, not if its a real file or folder)
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

    <IfModule mod_php5.c>
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
    </IfModule>

    <IfModule !mod_php5.c>
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
    </IfModule>

</IfModule>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that anyone will find this helpful, but the issue was only caused by mod_rewrite not being installed on our Apache. I was able to determine this by examining the output of phpinfo() in the browser. Here's a code example, not that you need it ;)

```
<?php print_r(phpinfo()) ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

try
I worked v 2.3 (host, DreamHost)

[pyrocms documentation removing index](https://www.pyrocms.com/documentation/2.0/getting-started/removing-index-php)

luck!